# Convert Unicode Javascript string to PHP utf8 string

Tags: javascript, php, string, utf-8

I make form with input text.

```
<input type="text" id="input" value=""/>
```

i received utf-8 string from web like this (with javascript, jquery)

```
var str = '\u306e\u7c21\u5358\u306a\u8aac\u660e';
```

str is 'の簡単な説明'.

set input field value to 'str'

```
$('#input').val(str);
```

this input replace all of escape string '\' and set string like this.

```
<input type"text" id="input" value="u306eu7c21u5358u306au8aacu660e"/>
```

no problem in this point. display character is also good.

[image]

But.

When I save this string into my database with PHP

PHP put this value non-escaped utf8 string 'u306eu7c21u5358u306au8aacu660e' to database

and next time I've call

```
<input type="text" id="input" value="<?=$str?>">
```

and browser displays raw value

just 'u306eu7c21u5358u306au8aacu660e'

not 'の簡単な説明'

[image]

I don't know what is wrong.

I've tried

```
$str = json_decode("\"".$str."\"");
html_entity_decode(...);
mb_convert_encoding(...);
```

but not working correctly...

How can I covert this non-escaped utf-8 string to general utf-8 string?

Comment: `u306eu7c21` is ***not*** "UTF-8". It's a string with the characters "u306eu7c21". `\u....` happens to be an escape sequence in Javascript/JSON string literals, but "u306eu7c21" doesn't mean anything in any context. The text "の簡単な説明" encoded in UTF-8 (and properly interpreted) looks like "の簡単な説明", nothing else. There should be no decoding, encoding, stripping or converting going on at any point. What if you take all those string manipulation steps out and just send the value as is?

Comment: @deceze the main problem is $('#input').val("utf-8 encoded string") method force to change '\u' to 'u' and php accepts 'uxxxxuxxxx....' string. server response is right. utf-8 encoded string replies like '\uxxxx\uxxxx'

Comment: I don't know, this seems weird. Can you post the smallest possible example that reproduces this problem? My guess would be you don't literally have `var str = '\u306e...'`, you're getting `\u306e...` from the server somewhere (AJAX JSON?) and are already failing to decode it properly or something.

Comment: @deceze yes something weird. it is hard to post example. code is massive. anyway i've fixed this issue with using regex replace u[0-9a-fA-F] -> to \u[0-9a-fA-F].  before store to database.

Answer (score 2):

You've MUST have MultiByte String support. With some extra work here is what you need:

```
<?php

$str = 'u306eu7c21u5358u306au8aacu660e';

function converter($sequence) {
    return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $sequence), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');  
}
# array_filter is not important here at all it just "remove" empty strings
$converted = array_map('converter', array_filter(explode('u', $str)));
$converted = join('', $converted);

print $converted;
```

> Just as a side note you **OUGHT TO FIND** a better strategy in order to
>   split the unicode sequences. By  "exploding" string by `u` char is
>   somewhat ingenuo.

Also, I strongly advise you read the excelent blog post by Armin Ronacher, [UCS vs UTF-8 as Internal String Encoding](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2014/1/9/ucs-vs-utf8/).

Comment: Note that you should avoid sending garbage like "u306e" to your server in the first place. Your solution is working if you can't fix the sending side, but you should avoid having to use this as your last resort at all.

Comment: Thank you. but why javascript $('#..').val(...) converts utf8 string to non-escaped string?

Comment: @deceze yep! Actually It's better set the properly encoding in database an store the value as it is.